# Is it possible to make Finder order on modified at, recursively?

Tags: macos, finder

If I visit `~/code` in Finder and order on `modified at` it does not recursively order. That is, if I have a file X in it which was modified yesterday and a folder with a file Y in it that was modified today, file X would be ordered before the folder with Y in it. Can it be achieved?

If that is not possible, is there a script that is triggered each time a file is saved which touches the parent folder to get same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by creating a script which watches for file writes and touches the written file's parent to update its modified timestamp.

[fswatch](https://github.com/emcrisostomo/fswatch) is needed too watch for writes. 
Install through homebrew with `brew install fswatch`.

Then follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6442364/running-script-upon-login-mac/6445525#6445525 
TL;DR

- Start Automator.app
- Cmd + N
- Add "Run shell script" (from the Actions/Utilities)
- Copy-and-paste your script into the window

  `fswatch -0 ~/ | while read -d "" event do touch -cm $(dirname ${event}); done`

  You can modify `~/` to a path of your liking.
- Save it as `touch_parent.app`
- Go to System Preferences → Accounts → Login items
- Add touch_parent.app

Next time you restart it will start the script